# PHP Array Sort Data

Tags: php

How can i get best way to get cheapest price from this php code ?

```
Array
    (
        [SKU0001901] => Array
            (
                [0] => 300000
                [1] => 50000
            )

        [SKU0001902] => Array
            (
                [0] => 400
                [1] => 2000000
                [2] => 500
            )

        [SKU0001903] => Array
            (
                [0] => 100000
                [1] => 500000
            )

    )
```

Expect : SKU0001901 is 50000 ,
SKU0001902 cheapest is 400, etc.

**SOLVED**

There many ways to answer my question. In my case, i use array_map.

```
$o = array_map('min', $array);
```

In the future, i want to make a research which method to make it faster, especially in big array data.

Comment: what you have tried till yet?

Comment: use `uasort()`.

Comment: finally i've found 3 ways to exect, but bad news when i got negative question. No prob, thanks everyone who already gave the best answer. Thumbs up for 3 of you.

Comment: thanks remind me. done. Looks good now. @mickmackusa

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just map `min` to your array:

```
$o = array_map('min', $array);
```

#### [Here's a demo](https://eval.in/787017)

Answer (score 2):

Simplest one with `array_map` and `sort`

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/787020)

```
<?php
$array= array( 
        'SKU0001901' =>  array(300000,50000),
        'SKU0001902' => array(400,2000000,500),
        'SKU0001903' =>  array(100000,500000));
$array=array_map(function($value){
    sort($value,SORT_NUMERIC);
    return $value[0];
}, $array);
print_r($array);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [SKU0001901] => 50000
    [SKU0001902] => 400
    [SKU0001903] => 100000
)
```

Comment: Running well, but i tried another answer below,
such :

$o = array_map('min', $array);

very simple, could you help to explain it ? Strongest and weakness ?

Comment: @Bobby In that user is trying to find minimum value from an array, which can't be helpful in case you have string in array `by chance`.

Comment: ah ic , so the different is data type, isnt it ?
I'll try to check the code performance by using same assume (min int value) from an array (big array).

thank you

Comment: @SahilGulati no, providing the string is numeric it'll work just fine

Comment: @billyonecan Sorry to say.. I am sure it will not work.. I have tested it.

Comment: @Bobby The below code also works in the same way.. The way i am doing my code below code will also fail in case of a string when string arises which in a `non-numeric`

Comment: @SahilGulati that's expected, it's a non-numeric string, your code will fail in [exactly the same way](https://eval.in/787051).

Comment: @billyonecan Thanks ... :) i have checked both the codes just read my last comment..

Answer (score 1):

This will work in your case.

```
$array_full= array( array('SKU0001901' =>  array(300000,50000),'SKU0001902' => array(400,2000000,500),'SKU0001903' =>  array(100000,500000)));
foreach($array_full[0] as $key=>$aaa){
    echo $key.' : '.min($aaa).'<br>';
}
```

You can use `min` to get lowest from array

Comment: Running well, but i tried another answer above, such : $o = array_map('min', $array); very simple, could you help to explain you code ? Strongest and weakness ?

Comment: `array_map` is way better then my answer! :P

Comment: If your work is done without `foreach` then it's awesome! *NOTE:* try to avoid `foreach` as much as possible in case of `array`

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple, you can use `foreach` and `sort`.

Read more about the different array sorting methods [here](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php).

Use `sort($v)` in the `foreach` loop which sorts lowest to highest and does not preserve key indexes, so the 0th item in this array will always be the smallest value.

```
<?php
$input =  [
  'SKU0001901' => [
    300000,
    50000,
  ],
  'SKU0001902' => [
    400,
    2000000,
    500,
  ],
  'SKU0001903' => [
    100000,
    500000,
  ]
];

$output = [];
foreach ($input as $k => $v) {
  sort($v);
  $output[$k] = $v[0];
}
print_r($output);
```

Produces:

```
Array
(
    [SKU0001901] => 50000
    [SKU0001902] => 400
    [SKU0001903] => 100000
)
```